# What is the best way to verify multiple jcombobox item selection?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, jcombobox

What is the best way to verify if a specific combination of two symbols is already selected in a several couples of jcomboboxes? This question is refered to a situation in which I have e. g. 10 options and for each of those I can assign a combination of two symbols where first one is from [ALT, CTRL, SHIFT] vector and second one is from [letters and numbers] vector. Both vectors are visualized in JComboBoxes (for each option are two combo boxes).

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Providing the code you're working with and pointing out what isn't working would be better as I think I understand what you're trying to acheive but without seeing how you're implementing this, I can't formulate a answer that might help you.

Comment: Each of your combo boxes should probably have a default value like "Select Modifier" and "Select Character", and they would be the first item in the combo box. So then you just need to make sure that both selected items are non-zero when you are ready to do your processing.

Answer (score 0):

Put couples of jcomboboxes into different buckets. Those couples that have ALT selected in first combobox go to the 1st one, those who have CTRL selected - to the 2nd one, SHIFT - to the 3rd one. Then see whether the same option in the second combobox is selected within the buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for answers. Finally I manage this problem this way:

```
    // Method For KeyGroup 1
public boolean isAlreadyKeyEvent(int index) {
     int vector[] = {combo_1_group1.getSelectedIndex(), combo_2_group1.getSelectedIndex(), combo_n_group1.getSelectedIndex()};
     int x = 0;
     for (int i : vector) {
          if (i == index) {
               x++;
          }
     }
     if (x > 1) {
          return true;
     } else {
          return false;
     }
}

// Method For KeyGroup 2
public boolean isAlreadyInputEvent(int index) {
     int vector[] = {combo_1_group2.getSelectedIndex(), combo_2_group2.getSelectedIndex(), combo_n_group2.getSelectedIndex()};
     int x = 0;
     for (int i : vector) {
          if (i == index) {
               x++;
          }
     }
     if (x > 1) {
          return true;
     } else {
          return false;
     }
}

combo_1_group2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

          boolean one = isAlreadyKeyEvent(combo_1_group2.getSelectedIndex());
          boolean two = isAlreadyInputEvent(combo_1_group1.getSelectedIndex());

          if (one) {
               if (two) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Such shortcut already exists! \n" + 
               "Choose something else.");
                    combo_1_group2.setSelectedIndex(Settings.combo_1_group2);
               } else {
                   Settings.combo_1_group2 = combo_1_group2.getSelectedIndex();
               }
          } else {
              Settings.combo_1_group2 = combo_1_group2.getSelectedIndex();
          }     
     }
});
```

So basically I've wrote two quite similar methods and also I've created a new class with static fields for values store. All works great :)